# Magento 2 plugin for catching order creating in frontend and in admin panel

Tags: magento2, plugin

I want to catch the moment of creating order - both in frontend by client and in administration panel by user. I've got a plugin for it:

```
class Plugin
{

    public function afterSave(
        $subject,
        $order, $additional = []
    )
    {
        exit('aftersave');
    }

    public function afterPlace(
        $subject,
        $order, $additional = []
    )
    {
        $order_id = $order->getEntityId(); // this is null
        exit('afterPlace');
    }

}
```

The afterSave method is not executed when creating order. The second - afterPlace method is executed, but I cat't get the entity id.

How to do it? What method should I listen to or how to get the order id?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a observer.

You can observe the following events

sales_order_place_after

sales_order_place_before

You can use this [Magento 2 Module Creator](https://mage2gen.com) to create example code.

Fill in the observer form an generate code.

With in the observer class method you can get the order like this

$order = $observer->getOrder();

$order->setSomething('test');

$order->save(); // Dont use this if you listen to a save event!!

Succes!